# Lookup with dynamic parameter in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

In my Rails 5 application I need to be able to lookup data based on the type of the incoming `params[:id]` value that is being send from a 3rd party app. Each Model has two unique identifiers: `id` and `cuid`, and the received value can be either one of them. The problem is easily is illustrated like this:

```
if params[:id][/^\d+$/] # if it is numeric
  @shipment = Shipment.find(params[:id])
elsif params[:id].present?
  @shipment = Shipment.find_by_cuid(params[:id])
end
```

In the routes I have to define what parameter to use for lookup, e.g.:

```
resources :shipments, param: :cuid
```

But that ofc doesn't do the trick if I need to be able to lookup dynamically in both columns based on the data-type (and yes, I know that the incoming type will always be string by default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with defining a global scope in `application_record.rb` with the following content:

```
scope :get_by_id_or_cuid, -> (id) do
  id.to_i.to_s == id.to_s ? find(id) : find_by_cuid(id)
end
```

So from now on I will call `get_by_id_or_cuid` instead of `find_by_id`.